# Convertible top vinyl small crack repair

Tags: ford, repair, mustang, soft-top

So I have a 2012 convertible V6 Ford Mustang and there is a very small crack developing in a crease on my roof:

[image: Vinyl Tear]

I believe the top is made from Vinyl and I must confess that I've neglected it. The first 2 years of the cars life were outdoors and I tried to clean off crud with water when it got on there, the last 2 1/2 years have been garaged and the car has only been out in good weather.

How can I mend this tear, and what kind of stuff do I need to treat the top with to prevent this from happening again? I'd like for this baby to last!

Here is a slightly larger view of the roof - I'm pointing at the location of the crack:

[image: Crack Location]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a flexible epoxy or something like a cloth/heavy-duty repair tape: http://www.gorillatough.com/gorilla-clear-repair or https://www.mcnett.com/gearaid/tenacious-tape#10691

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with ["Loctite Vinyl, Fabric and Plastic Repair Adhesive"](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001F7E9VI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). The link is not to specifically advertise a product, but so that others can see the gist of what I purchased. It's clear and it went on well enough. The crack is small and hopefully this will keep it from expanding! Time will tell.

Comment: Must confess that the Loctite adhesive did not last very long and wasn't effective. Sold the car about a month ago and the crack had not increased in size too much. Prevention or replacement seem to be the only good options...